# $e^{e^{10^{10^{2.8}}}}$ changing $e$ with $10$

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation, tetration

From [Numberphile](https://youtu.be/1GCf29FPM4k?t=8m55s) $$e^{e^{10^{10^{2.8}}}}$$ changing $e$ with $10$, is there a way to change only the top most number while keeping all other numbers 10? i.e what is x in :

$$e^{e^{10^{10^{2.8}}}} = 10^{10^{10^{10^{x}}}} $$

Comment: Take natural logs of both sides twice, expand, drop the insignificant $\ln \ln 10$ additive term, rewrite $\ln 10$ as $10^{y},$ get $10^{10^{2.8}} = 10^{10^{x+y}},$ take base-10 logs of both sides twice, get $2.8 = x + y,$ subtract $y$ from both sides. (I have to leave right now and I did this fast, so there might be an oversight somewhere.)

Answer (score 1):

In general, not necessarily. The left-hand side needs to be big enough. The smallest we can get is if we let $x \to -\infty$, which gives us
$$
10^{10^{10^{10^{x}}}} \to 10^{10^{10^{10^{-\infty}}}} \to 10^{10^{10^{0}}}=10^{10^{1}} = 10^{10}
$$
so basically, we cannot reach down to $10^{10}$, but any number above that is large enough that we can find an $x$ that takes us there. Clearly, $e^{e^{10^{10^{2.8}}}}$ is large enough.

Following Dave's comment above, we can find an (approximate) $x$ the following way (letting $\ln$ be the natural logarithm and $\log$ the base-ten logarithm):
$$
e^{e^{10^{10^{2.8}}}} = 10^{10^{10^{10^{x}}}}\\
e^{10^{10^{2.8}}} = 10^{10^{10^{x}}}\ln 10\\
10^{10^{2.8}} = 10^{10^{x}}\ln(10) + \ln(\ln 10) \approx 10^{10^x}\ln(10)\\
10^{10^{2.8}} \approx 10^{10^x + \log(\ln 10)}\\
10^{2.8} \approx 10^x + \log(\ln 10)\\
x \approx 2.7997506116
$$
so we actually don't have to change the exponent much. The approximation of throwing away $\ln(\ln 10) \approx 0.83$ happens at a stage where both sides have $630$ digits, so it doesn't change much. The $\log(\ln 10)$, however, is then the only thing left that separates the two cases, so we have to keep that, and at that stage, the two sides have *value* at around $630$ instead, so it has a much greater impact on the result anyways.

Answer (score 1):

First, we have

$$ e^{\textstyle 10^{10^{2.8}}} = 
  10^{\textstyle \log_{10}(e) \cdot 10^{10^{2.8}}} =
  10^{\textstyle 10^{\left( 10^{2.8} + \log_{10}\log_{10}(e) \right)}} =
  10^{\textstyle 10^{10^{A}}} $$
where
$$A = \log_{10}(10^{2.8} + \log_{10}\log_{10}(e)) \approx \log_{10}(630.96 - 0.36) \approx 2.7998 $$

Now, setting $B=10^{10^A}$, do the same once more:
$$ e^{\textstyle e^{\textstyle 10^{10^{2.8}}}} =
 e^{\textstyle 10^B} =
 10^{\textstyle \log_{10}(e)\cdot 10^B} =
 10^{\textstyle 10^{B+\log_{10}\log_{10}(e)}} $$
But $\log_{10}\log_{10}(e)$ is still only $-0.36$, whereas $B$ has hundreds of digits before the decimal point, so this equals
$$ 10^{\textstyle 10^{\textstyle 10^{10^C}}} $$
for a $C$ that is so close to $A\approx2.7998$ that it isn't even funny.

**Moral:** The values of the bottommost bases in a power tower matter very little in the great scheme of things.

Comment: Lol! I laughed, so it must be funny!